# Retrieving Activities returns undefined error from getstream.io API

Tags: javascript, getstream-io

I am following the documentation steps of [getstream](http://getstream.io) and everything went well until the "[Retrieving Activities](https://getstream.io/docs/?language=js#retrieve)" step.

---

Running

```
import stream from 'getstream' // stream-js v3.5.0
const client = stream.connect(APP_KEY, null, APP_ID, { location: 'eu-west' });
const user1 = client.feed('user', '1', READ_ONLY_TOKEN);

user1.get({ limit:5, offset:5 })
  .catch((errorData) => {
    console.log(errorData);
  });
```

gives me

```
{
    error: undefined,
    response: {
        statusCode: 0,
        request: {
            uri: {
                protocol: "https:",
                slashes: true,
                auth: null,
                host: "api.getstream.io",
                port: null,
                hostname: "api.getstream.io",
                hash: null,
                search: "?limit=5&offset=5&api_key=...secret...&location=unspecified",
                query: "limit=5&offset=5&api_key=...secret...&location=unspecified",
                pathname: "/api/v1.0/feed/global/global/",
                path: "/api/v1.0/feed/global/global/?limit=5&offset=5&api_key=...secret...&location=unspecified",
                href: "https://api.getstream.io/api/v1.0/feed/global/global/?limit=5&offset=5&api_key=...secret...&location=unspecified"
            },
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                stream - auth - type: "jwt",
                Authorization: "...secret...",
                ["X-Stream-Client"]: "stream-javascript-client-browser-unknown",
                accept: "application/json"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Any suggestion of what I could try here?

Comment: Can you specify which of our SDKs you're using? passing your key and secret on a GET request isn't how our SDKs work and exposes your credentials. Normally our stream-js library would have you connecting and pulling data this way: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-js#usage

Comment: you mean the version of the stream-js I have running? 3.5.0. I updated the question with more details, and I believe I am already connecting to getstream in the right way :) @iandouglas

Comment: The code snippet and the error don't seem to match; can you check again how the feed object is initialized?

Comment: what do you mean, @TommasoBarbugli? that's the code, I checked it many times.

Comment: I posted an issue in the project's repository given that it is hard to keep the information updated in SO. It can be checked at https://github.com/GetStream/stream-js/issues/99

Comment: A reproducible has also been created and is available at https://github.com/zvictor/stream-bug

Comment: What I meant is that the error shows a request to URL "/api/v1.0/feed/global/global/" but code is reading feed "user:1" (/api/v1.0/feed/user/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug, described at [GetStream/stream-js#99](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-js/issues/99), that has just been fixed by the getstream.io team.

@JelteF:

> I found out the problem. Meteor has its own browser fallback for the
>   request lib that has a different default for withCredentials. This
>   overrides the request browser library that I mentioned before. PR #100
>   should fix this by setting withCredentials explicitly.

...

> I merged it into master, you can use install from there for now until it is released.

Thank you all for the hard work!